# Selecting summed values of gold

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables with people's gold earnings. When a user is earning some gold a new record is going to one of these tables with `e_user` and `f_value`.

Now I want to sum all the gold of every user and select the ones who earned less than 1000.

```
select count(e_user) from (
    select count(e_user) from quest_gold union all
    select count(e_user) from monster_gold union all
    select count(e_user) from other_gold 
) AS money

where f_value < 1000
group by e_user
```

I am not sure if my select is even going the right way but it gives me "unknown syntax error" right now. Please tell me what is wrong here.

Comment: first of all you said you want to **sum** but then you used **count** . How you explain that

Comment: Well all I want to do is to get the number of people whose sum of money is less than 1000

Answer (score 1):

You can use `having` clause to filter user less than 1000, but not `count(f_user)`, it's `sum(f_value)`:

```
select e_user, sum(f_value) as sum_val
from (
    select e_user, f_value from quest_gold union all
    select e_user, f_value from monster_gold union all
    select e_user, f_value from other_gold 
) as money
group by e_user
having sum_val < 1000
```

Comment: Very good. OP's own query completely confused me. Thumbs up for getting this straight.

Answer (score 0):

Users who earned less then 1000 gold should include those who earned nothing. Hence:

```
select u.user, coalesce(earned.gold, 0) as earned_gold
from users u
left join
(
  select e_user, sum(f_value) as gold
  from
  (
    select e_user, f_value from quest_gold
    union all
    select e_user, f_value from monster_gold
    union all
    select e_user, f_value from other_gold
  ) all_gold
  group by e_user
) earned on earned.e_user = u.user and earned.gold < 1000
order by u.user;
```

If you just want to count the number of users with less then 1000 gold:

```
select count(earned.e_user) as poor_users
from users u
left join
(
  select e_user, sum(f_value) as gold
  from
  (
    select e_user, f_value from quest_gold
    union all
    select e_user, f_value from monster_gold
    union all
    select e_user, f_value from other_gold
  ) all_gold
  group by e_user
) earned on earned.e_user = u.user and earned.gold < 1000;
```